# Why are these .htaccess rules causing recursion?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, openshift

What is it about the rules below that could be causing a recursion?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|robots\.txt|js|files|icons|fonts)
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /doacoes/index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I searched for some solutions to this problem, no luck. It doesn't happen locally, only when I deploy the app to OpenShift.

Comment: 1. `RewriteBase` can't be there. 2. Do not use negative patterns with alternatives, as it may be your logical error.

Comment: It wassn't there originally. It was in one of the solutions I've found. The `[L,QSA]` is another. Well, I removed it and now it works. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Deadooshka you should post that as an answer so that it can be marked as correct.